# ElasticSearch painless, how can I access an array in _source

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to execute a search request to the ElasticSearch (6.4.0) API which includes a custom script function. In this function I try to access an array which should part of the response data. But I always get a 'null_pointer_exception':

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "runtime error",
            "script_stack": [
                "i = 0; i < params['_source']['userStats'].length; i++) { } ",
                "                 ^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script": "double scoreBoost = 1; for (int i = 0; i < params['_source']['userStats'].length; i++) { } return _score * Math.log1p(scoreBoost);",
            "lang": "painless"
        }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
        {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "search--project",
            "node": "...",
            "reason": {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "runtime error",
                "script_stack": [
                    "i = 0; i < params['_source']['userStats'].length; i++) { } ",
                    "                 ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "double scoreBoost = 1; for (int i = 0; i < params['_source']['userStats'].length; i++) { } return _score * Math.log1p(scoreBoost);",
                "lang": "painless",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "null_pointer_exception",
                    "reason": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"status": 500
```

}

Also doc['userStats'] does't work.

Here is the complete request body:

```
{
"size": 10,
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "_routing": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                    }
                },
                "should": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "123*",
                        "default_operator": "and",
                        "fuzziness": 1,
                        "analyze_wildcard": true,
                        "fields": [
                            "name^4",
                            "number^2",
                            "description",
                            "projectTypeId",
                            "projectStatusId",
                            "tags^1.5",
                            "company.name^2",
                            "company.number^2",
                            "company.industry",
                            "company.tags^1.5",
                            "company.companyTypes.name",
                            "company.companyContactInfos.value",
                            "company.companyContactInfos.addressLine1^1.25",
                            "company.companyContactInfos.addressLine2",
                            "company.companyContactInfos.zipCode^0.5",
                            "company.companyContactInfos.city",
                            "company.companyContactInfos.state",
                            "company.companyContactInfos.country",
                            "projectType.id",
                            "projectType.name",
                            "projectType.description",
                            "projectStatus.id",
                            "projectStatus.name",
                            "members.name",
                            "members.projectRoleName"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "minimum_should_match": 1
            }
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "source": "double scoreBoost = 1; for (int i = 0; i < params['_source']['userStats'].length; i++) { } return _score * Math.log1p(scoreBoost);",
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "params": {
                            "dtNow": 1543589276,
                            "uId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
```

}

Without the script_score part the response look like this:

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 4,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "search--project",
            "_type": "projectentity",
            "_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "_score": 4,
            "_routing": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "_source": {
                "name": "123",
                "description": "123...",
                "projectTypeId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "projectStatusId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "tags": [
                    "232",
                    "2331",
                    "343"
                ],
                "plannedDuration": 0,
                "startDate": "2018-07-09T22:00:00Z",
                "projectType": {
                    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "name": "test 1",
                    "icon": "poll"
                },
                "projectStatus": {
                    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "name": "In Progress",
                    "type": "progress"
                },
                "members": [
                    {
                        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "name": "dummy",
                        "projectRoleName": "test",
                        "hasImage": false
                    },
                    {
                        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "name": "dummy ",
                        "projectRoleName": "Manager",
                        "hasImage": false
                    }
                ],
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "userStats": [
                    {
                        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "openCount": 55,
                        "lastOpened": 1543851773
                    },
                    {
                        "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "openCount": 9,
                        "lastOpened": 1542372179
                    }
                ],
                "indexTime": "2018-12-03T15:42:53.157649Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

The mapping look like this:

```
{
"search--project": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "projectentity": {
            "_routing": {
                "required": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "company": {
                    "properties": {
                        "companyTypes": {
                            "properties": {
                                "icon": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "indexTime": {
                                    "type": "date"
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "fields": {
                                        "keyword": {
                                            "type": "keyword",
                                            "ignore_above": 256
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "indexTime": {
                            "type": "date"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "number": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "members": {
                    "properties": {
                        "hasImage": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "projectRoleName": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "userId": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                ...
                "plannedDuration": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "startDate": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "userStats": {
                    "properties": {
                        "lastOpened": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "openCount": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "userId": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1539619646426",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "G5ohN1FvQBGkYFh_803Ifw",
            "version": {
                "created": "6040299"
            },
            "provided_name": "search--project"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Anyone has a suggestion what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the query you have your `params` identified as `dtdNow` and `uid`. So if you're wanting to use those in your script you would do the `params.dtdNow`.

If you're wanting to use a property from your `_source` (i.e. `userStats`) you should be using `ctx._source.userStats.length`. There are more examples in the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html.

**EDIT**

With a function_score query you'll either be using the `doc` map or `params['_source']`. The difference being that when you use `doc` it gets cached in memory and `params['_source']` will be loaded up each time (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html). The other caveat is that you need to use a non-analyzed field *or* an analyzed `text` field if `fielddata` is enabled. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals

To achieve what you're trying do, you should be able to just use a non-analyzed field in your `userStats` object. Something like this `doc['userStats.openCount'].length` (here I'm assuming that `openCount` is required on your `userStats` object).

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer.
I definitely want to access data of my source. But when I try 'ctx._source.userStats.length', I got an 'illegal_argument_exception' with the reason: "type":  'Variable [ctx] is not defined.'

Comment: Ah, sorry. In a function_score, you would use `doc['userStats']` but I do believe that the field you use needs to be a non analyzed field. What is the mapping for your index?

Comment: Hey, I added an example of the mapping above. We have no special creation of indexes, we use the dynamic index creation.

Comment: I updated my answer. You'll need to use a non analyzed field in your script. Otherwise the field will not be found in the `doc` map.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your help. I will try to change my mapping.